# Returning JSON Objects from jeJSrsey Rest Service

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I have a rest service which returns JSONObjects and JSONArrays

I m trying to return

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONArray;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

from my Rest service.

ex :

```
 @Path("/SubgraphIds")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONArray getSubgraphIds() {

       .......

    }

    @Path("/Subgraph/id={id}/startTime={startTime}/duration={duration}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject getSubgraph(@PathParam("id")String id ,@PathParam("startTime")String startTime ,
                              @PathParam("duration")String duration) {

    }
```

In my application i internally start my Own Rest service within the application by using com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver

/**
             * Starting Service
             */
            this.resourceConfig = new PackagesResourceConfig(restPkg);

```
        resourceConfig.getFeatures().put(ClientConfig.FEATURE_DISABLE_XML_SECURITY, true);
        resourceConfig.getProperties().put(ClientConfig.FEATURE_DISABLE_XML_SECURITY, "true");
        resourceConfig.getClasses().add(JSONArrayProvider.class);
        resourceConfig.getClasses().add(JSONArrayProvider.class);
        this.httpServer = HttpServerFactory.create(getURL(port), resourceConfig);
```

But I get Following Error when starting the server. Any thoughts on resolving this is highly appreciated. (I m using jersey-core,jersey-server,jersey-json 1.1.1-ea verions).

SEVERE: The provider class, class com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider, could not be instantiated. Processing will continue but the class will not be utilized
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor can not access a member of class com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:368)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.*getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:152)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ComponentConstructor.getInstance(ComponentConstructor.java:140)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.*_getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:159)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory._getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:152)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:146)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderFactory.getComponentProvider(ProviderFactory.java:124)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getComponent(ProviderServices.java:190)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getProvidersAndServices(ProviderServices.java:120)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:145)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:130)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory.create(HttpServerFactory.java:169)

Comment: To convert object to / from JSON, you should consider Jackson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
resourceConfig.getClasses().add(JSONArrayProvider.class);
```

lines from your code. Providers for `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` are found automatically via `META-INF\services` mechanism. Everything you need to do to use these Jettison classes is to put `jersey-json.jar` and `jettison.jar` on your classpath.